# Could we please clean up the kde/plasma tags?

Tags: discussion, status-planned

Currently, there are several kde/plasma tags that are similar.

- [kde5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kde5) (40 questions) and [plasma5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plasma5) (37 questions)
- [kde](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kde) (771 questions) and [plasma](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plasma) (72 questions)
- There is also [kde4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kde4) (63 questions)

It's my understanding that KDE is the community that creates the Plasma desktop environment. However, KDE also creates other software, including KDE Frameworks. I'm unsure what the `kde[45]?` tags specifically denote. The [kde](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kde) tag description says:

> a full featured desktop environment and collection of software for communication, work, education and entertainment.

which includes everything that the KDE community creates, I suppose.

There is also the issue of three `kde[45]?` tags. Similarly, there are two Plasma-related tags.

- [plasma](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plasma)

  > the umbrella term for all graphical environments provided by KDE.
- [plasma5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plasma5)

  > for KDE Plasma 5-related questions. Plasma 5 is the fifth generation of desktop environment from KDE.

I guess having both is a historical thing. When Plasma 5 was released, a distinct tag was necessary. However, since most people are now using Plasma 5, most questions could be tagged with both. In addition, these questions could also be tagged with [kde](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kde) and [kde5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kde5) too!

Could we merge some of the tags, and/or blacklist some of them, and if so, how?

Comment: We can merge and make tag synonyms, although I'm not sure what the right tags should be. Theoretically tags with a version number are specific to that version, but I'd guess that's not how they're used much of the time. If the KDE tags include non-Plasma stuff then having four separate tags might be right

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I just found it odd that in theory, a question relating to Plasma 5 could (should?) be tagged with four tags. Also, a broader question, but what are tags really for? Are they to let potential users track future questions in which they might be interested? If so, then presumably most people who are interested in KDE would also be interested in Plasma. So I guess Plasma could probably be removed?

Comment: A subset of this question has been [asked](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4672/18887), to merge the kde5 and plasma5 parts.