# Merge [kde5] & [plasma5]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request

[`kde5`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/kde5/info) & [`plasma5`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/plasma5/info) mean the same thing.
As explained by the [Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/kde-plasma-5/info) equivalent, Plasma 5 is the fifth iteration of KDE's desktop environment (`kde5`, on its own, makes no sense).
For this reason I'm in favour of migrating/burninating `kde5` to be replaced with `plasma5`.

However, many people don't realise their environment is called "plasma", someone asking a question may begin to type in "kde" as a tag; it won't auto-suggest `plasma5` for them (as `kde5` would be).
I solved this on SU by naming the tag `kde-plasma-5`.

Almost all questions I looked at under either of these tags were tagged with the other also.
Whether we move both, keep plasma, or keep kde, they do need to be merged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could we please clean up the kde/plasma tags?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/could-we-please-clean-up-the-kde-plasma-tags)

Comment: Very good idea with the `kde-plasma-5` part though. Maybe you can put that in the original question?

Comment: I didn't want to add to that question since it's more about cleaning *all* the kde/plasma related tags. I don't have a solution for that, but I do for the sub-problem regarding kdeX & plasmaX. That issue could take ages to resolve, but this particular merge request is a no-brainer and can happen now, separate to how they decide to handle the other tags later

Comment: Yes, fair call. Apologies, I've retracted my close vote (+1).

Comment: No worries, this is a `discussion` meta, so I was always open to those kind of flags appearing